# interact with a smartcontract with nodejs in a private network

Tags: node.js, ethereum, truffle

I would like to make a nodejs app to interact with a smartcontract in a private chain ethereum.
By using truffle console it is done like this and works right :

```
var dApp
Hello.deployed().then(function(instance) { dApp = instance; })
dApp.message.call()
```

I would like to do the same with nodejs.

here is my code :

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var contract = require("truffle-contract");
var provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:2122");
var abi = [ { constant: true, inputs: [],... } ]
var bin = '0x60806....';
var contract_address = "0x4321881a....";
var Hello = contract({abi: abi, unlinked_binary: bin });
Hello.at(contract_address)
Hello.setProvider(provider);
Hello.deployed().then((i) => { i.message.call() })
```

when launching i have this error :

```
(node:7735) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
```

Comment: Try creating the new contract with abi and the deployed contract address like this,      
 `var web3 = new Web3(provider);                                                                        
  var Hello = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,address);`

Comment: can you please include more of the stack trace on the error?

Comment: We need more info about the error, yet `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` is caused because some of your functions are asyncronous, and its being executed before it can be resolved, try putting they keyword `await` before the ascyncronous function.